# Stop Brackets Editor from wrapping my code (HTML,CSS,JS or PHP)

Tags: editor, text-editor, adobe-brackets

How can i stop Brackets editor from wrapping my code onto the next-line. If my code line is too long for my screen, i prefer to scroll horizontally rather than have my editor fold or wrap it, making it had for me to understand my own code blocks.

I have tried looking for extensions...that didn't work. I also tried to look for settings which seem to be non existent or minimal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's `View > Word Wrap` toggle which you can use to disable this option.

Comment: It's _View > Word Wrap_ -- just uncheck that.